# Como pegar as unidades de um número de dois dígitos

Tags: php

Preciso pegar as unidades de um número de dois dígitos com PHP.

exemplo:

```
$num = 25;
$dig1 = 2;
$dig2 = 5;
```

Comment: Quer separa o números por dígitos, isso?

Comment: Só quero pegar a unidade deles, o primeiro digito, e o segundo, e criar um numero a parte, como está vendo no exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar a unidade, basta calcular o resto de divisão por 10:

```
$num = 25;
echo $num % 10; // Imprime 5
```

E para a dezena, basta pegar a parte inteira da divisão por 10:

```
$num = 25;
echo intdiv($num, 10); // Imprime 2
```

O mesmo funciona para valores negativos:

```
$num = -25;
echo intdiv($num, 10) . PHP_EOL; // Imprime -2
echo $num % 10 . PHP_EOL; // Imprime -5
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Jgvy5a).

#### PHP 5

Como a função `intdiv` só foi introduzida na versão 7 do PHP, uma alternativa para o PHP 5 é utilizar a função `round`:

```
echo round($num/10, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

O primeiro valor refere-se ao valor a ser arredondado; o segundo refere-se ao número de casas decimais e o terceiro se o mesmo deve ser arredondado para baixo. Desta forma, retornaria 2 para `$num = 25` e -2 para `$num = -25`.

Comment: a função intdiv() não está funcionando aqui, está dizendo que ela não existe

Comment: @RicardoParizSilva, desculpe-me, esta função só foi introduzida na versão 7 do PHP. Editarei a resposta com uma alternativa para o PHP 5.

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

No php toda string pode ser considerada um array de caracteres e é possivel fazer um cast de int para string, então pode-se conseguir os digitos de um numero assim

No PHP 7

```
$num = 25;
$dig1 = ((string)abs($num))[0];
$dig2 = ((string)abs($num))[1];
```

No PHP >= 5.4

```
$num = 25;
$dig1 = strval(abs($num))[0];
$dig2 = strval(abs($num))[1];
```

Comment: Também tem o problema se `$num` for negativo. A posição 0 da *string* seria o sinal de menos.

Comment: Realmente, acho que não foi uma boa solução, corrigi para ao menos não ter esse problema

Comment: para o meu caso funciona, já que valido se o número é negativo antes de fazer operações com ele

Answer (score 1):

Divide por 10 e pega o resto da divisão.

```
$num = 25;
$unidades = 25 % 10; // retorna 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar a função [str_split()](http://php.net/str_split) do php

```
$array = str_split($num);
```

Comment: Se `$num` for negativo, o resultado perde o sentido.

Comment: se no teu caso for permitido, Poderás sempre fazer o seguinte `$array = str_split(abs($num));` Assim fará o valor Absoluto de `$num`

Comment: Neste caso resultaria em 2 e 5 (positivos), o que matematicamente não faz sentido. Se a entrada for apenas positiva, é uma solução, mas se puder ser negativa, o melhor é fazer pelas operações matemáticas.